# How can I clean out duplicate entries from my PATH?

Tags: path

Currently, my $PATH has two identical entries for `/usr/local/bin` and I'm curious whether there's a way to clean that up, or if I should just not worry about it. It looks like this (broken up into a readable list):

```
/Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
/Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin
/Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin
/usr/local/bin <--( Here )
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin <--( Here )
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/texbin
/Users/myself/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: Migrated on request of the OP. (Ivan, note that Linux and Unix questions are perfectly on topic for Super User too.)

Comment: With `zsh`: `typeset -U path`.

Comment: With `tcsh`: `set -f path = ($path:q)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is just redefine your path

```
export PATH=/Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:
/Users/myself/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:
/Users/myself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/opt/X11/bin:
/usr/texbin:
/Users/myself/.rvm/bin:
```

(You'll need to put all of this on one line.)

Though having a path defined twice won't hurt anything. Fixing it just depends how OCD you are.

To make this persist across reboots & new terminal windows, you'll need to modify your startup script ( ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, /etc/environment )

Comment: This is gold: "To make this persist across reboots & new terminal windows". Just spend an hour trying to figure out why entries in $PATH were in triplicate in iTerm. A restart fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have modified something somewhere and have added the same path twice. I avoid this by using a nice little function do modify my `$PATH` that will only add a directory if that s not already present:

```
pathmunge () {
        if ! echo $PATH | /bin/egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
           if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
              PATH=$PATH:$1
           else
              PATH=$1:$PATH
           fi
        fi
}
```

I have that function in my `.profile` file and define my path as:

```
pathmunge $HOME/bin
pathmunge $HOME/scripts
export PATH
```

Just go through your shells initialization files and use this method to avoind duplicates.

If you just want to quickly remove existing dupes, do this:

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | perl -lne 'chomp; print unless $k{$_}; $k{$_}++' | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$//')
```

I am using `perl` instead of `sort -u` to keep the order of the directories unchanged.